# Localize a CustomAction programmatically

Tags: custom-actions

I work in a farm environment and i want to add a `CustomAction` in a specific `SPList`. The list is created programmatically, so i cannot know the `ID`. For that i tried to register the action with `RegistrationId="{$ListId:Lists/MyList;}"`.

```
<CustomAction
    Id="MyCustomAction"
    Location="CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView"
    RegistrationType="List"
    RegistrationId="{$ListId:Lists/MyList;}">

    ...

</CustomAction>
```

As i [read](http://www.elumenotion.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=119) and figure out, there is a bug in farm environment and i cannot register the action this way. I decided to add the action programmatically

```
SPUserCustomAction action = splist.UserCustomActions.Add();
action.Location = "CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView";
action.CommandUIExtension = @"
    <CommandUIExtension xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/'>
        <CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIDefinition Location='Ribbon.ListItem.Actions.Controls._children'>
                <Button
                    Id='MyCustomActionButton'
                    Command='MyCustomActionCommand'
                    Image16by16='/_images/info_16x16.png'
                    Image32by32='/_images/info_32x32.png'
                    LabelText='$Resources:MyResources,Title;'
                    TemplateAlias='o1'
                    Sequence='25'
                />
            </CommandUIDefinition>
        </CommandUIDefinitions>

        ...

    </CommandUIExtension>
";
action.Update();
```

Now action is registered successfully but the problem is with the button label text. How it can be localized through code?

**EDIT**

There is the property `CommandUIExtensionResource` in `SPUserCustomAction`, that i suppose i could use, but i cannot find any example. I have use `TitleResource` in `SPList`, but the same usage in this case does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. It seems to be that there is no way to add programmatically a localizable custom action.

Declarative custom actions are localizable. But to target them to a specific list in a declarative way we need to make templates of the custom list. I did not found a way to build a template for external lists.

So it seems to be impossible to add localizable custom actions to a specific external list.

Just because `RegistrationId="{$ListId:Lists/MyList;}"` does not work in farm solutions.

Do you have solved your problem?

Comment: no unfortunately i haven't found a solution

Comment: OK thank you! It is too bad that MS does not fix `RegistrationId="{$ListId:Lists/MyList;}"` for farm solutions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use MS SPUtility class to read resource files:

```
SPUtility.GetLocalizedString(
string.Format("$Resources:{0}", resourceKey), 
"name of your resource file", 
(uint)SPContext.Current.Web.Locale.LCID
);
```

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: If you are suggesting to localize the string to the current locale before creating the action, that would mean that the action will use a constant text. That also means that the action would not support MUI usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `GetGlobalResourceObject` to get the localized string

```
HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("name of your resource file", "resourceKey").ToString();
```

Comment: i think you didn't understand the question @Nizar